# Android Bluetooth getService returns null

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect a device with phone via bluetooth by calling following two function for the service. First one "mBluetoothGatt.getService(uuid)" and "BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getCharacteristic(UUID)".

Problem is sometimes one of the service returns null. Sometime back it was working correctly, but now its not working at all.

But it works when i restart the bluetooth of the phone. After sometime (5-6 mins) it again stops working.

Please help, on what steps to follows to debug further for getting it work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using getService inside the onServicesDiscovered() callback?

Comment: @CurlyCorvus, no we are not using getService() inside onServicesDiscovered() callback. Let me try to call it , inside it.

Comment: Which UUid are you passing in?

Comment: @MikeDocherty, we are creating app for BLE device related to health, so we are using
UUID_PEDOMETER_SERVICE="0000FFF0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"

Answer (score 1):

Test using a second device. It is very possible that there might an issue with your current device.

Comment: we have tried all the devices available with us (around 20-30) and all having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You said you're checking multiple devices, are you also checking on multiple software versions. From what I have found a lot of android 4.4.X have this issue. From what I have found there is no push to the latest version that fixes the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63056). This is a [resolution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1N6UUsopEM) that worked for some people.